# Getting class contains in a very simple Jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm experimenting with Jquery plugins. (please note I'm a beginner) and I've made a very simple plugin. this works if I set the selector to `('div')` but when I try to make it so it only selects the divs with a class that contains `"object"` it fails. what am I doing wrong? I'm not getting any errors.

javascript:

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.Duplo = function() {

        return this.filter("div[class*='object']").clone().appendTo('body');

    };

}( jQuery ));


$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".negen" ).Duplo();
});
```

html:

```
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 twaalf">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 drie">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 negen">

     <div class="object"></div>
     <div class="object2"></div> 
     <div class="object3"></div> 
     <div class="object4"></div> 
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

My html contains four divs with the `classes: object, object1, object2, object3` Also `.negen` is the div wich contains all of these.

Thanks :)

Comment: Provide relevant HTML markup of `.negen` element

Comment: I'll post my html too.

Comment: My first thought is you should use `.find()` not `.filter()`

Comment: What is your expected behaviour, clone `.negen` element wich contains elements with class '*=object' or clone this nested DIVs instead?

Comment: @A.Wolff changing `.filter()` to `.find()` solved the problem. thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure this is what you expect???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect to filter `.negen` elements which contains some specific elements with class containing `object`, then use:

```
this.filter(":has(div[class*='object'])").clone().appendTo('body');
```

This could be written as:

```
return this.has("div[class*='object']").clone().appendTo('body');
```

If you want to clone elements `object`, then use:

```
return this.find("div[class*='object']").clone().appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your selector statement

"("div[class*='object']")" this part

check this
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I've read that article but as far as I know I'm using the appropriate selector? I'm trying to get all that contains "object".

Comment: ok what do you need from the HTML , What is your expected result, I didnt got you, i will modify this answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
return this.find(".object").clone().appendTo('body');
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3bsJL/)